Compactness, Precompactness & Paracompactness
Def(1) Let $(X, \tau)$ a topological space, X is said to be Compact iff every open cover admits an a finite subcover.
Def(2) Let $(X, \tau)$ a topological space, X is said to be Paracompact iff every open cover admits an open refinement that is locally finite.
Def(3) Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, let $P \subset X$, P is said to be Precompact (on X) iff $cl_X(P)$ is compact.
It's clear to me that:
(1) Compact implies Paracompact
(2) Subset compactness doesn't imply precompacness of subset, CounterExample
Anyone know an example of subset such that is:

Paracompact and Precompact but not Compact
Paracompact but not Compact and Precompact

ADDENDUM:
Exist an example of Precompact that is not Paracompact?



Paracompact and Precompact but not Compact


Every metric space is paracompact. And therefore any bounded and non-closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be such example.


Paracompact but not Compact and Precompact


Again, we can look at metric spaces. Any unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an example.

The open unit interval $(0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is paracompact and precompact (in $\mathbb{R}$) but not compact.
The real line $\mathbb{R}$ is paracompact but not compact and not precompact as a subspace of itself.
